# Comparing two columns of different tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `Books_course` and `Books_count`. Problem comes when i make trigger. As soon as `Books_count` get updated it checks for the  value lets say 15 in `books_course` table. It compares both and if value exceeds it will print an message

Code:

```
create trigger alarm after update on books_status 

for each row begin 
  update table1 
    set count=new.count where book_id=new.book_id; 

   declare cnt1 , cnt2; 

   cnt1= select count from books_status; 
   cnt2 =select mini from books_course;

   if (cnt1 > cnt2 ) then 
      echo " fine"; 
   else 
      echo " order more books";
```

its giving the following error message ..

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=select Books_status.count; cnt2= select Books_course.mini; if (cnt1 > cnt2 ) th' at line 1
```

Comment: Why would you keep the error message a secret? How does that help anyone to help you?

Comment: Sorry But i m new to this site.Posted 1st time,so forgive if i made any mistake..please help me out

Comment: There's no need to apologize. There *is* a need to show the error you are getting - you can edit the question to add it at the bottom.

Comment: this code is not running..

Comment: This is a small part in my project.Iam doing my 1st project in mysql

Comment: I don't believe there is a MySQL error "this code is not running". Nobody can help you unless you give the actual error.

Comment: will show what error is coming..ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=select Books_status.count; cnt2= select Books_course.mini; if (cnt1 > cnt2 ) th' at line 1

Comment: You don't have "select Books_status.count" anywhere in the code above. That error message was not generated by the code you have supplied. I recommend you go away, create a small self-contained example (search for sqlfiddle) and post another question. Make sure you provide accurate information that time.

Answer (score 0):

*ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax** means your mysql statement has got some problem.

EDIT: Its normally an error triggered for an extra white space in your statement. So try to go over one more time, and avoid the spaces. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998705/mysql-problem-error-1064-42000)