# Error 1064 (42000):

Tags: sql, ddl

Could anyone please help me how to fix the following error.

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
   id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   username VARCHAR 
   username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   hashed_password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, hashed_password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY' at line 4

I need to delete 'username VARCHAR' line but couldn't figure out how to save the changes.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking, but it appears to be "How do I repeat previous commands on a terminal with some changes?", for which your search results are probably more relevant. (You also have a typo in `PRIMARY KAEY`.)

Comment: So... skip including that line next time you select a previous line to rerun? I don't get it. Terminal command history has (in my experience) no particular requirement to go in perfect sequence without skipping.

Comment: Could you please help me how to resolve the above error i am facing? ERROR 1064 (42000):

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL problem: ERROR 1064 (42000)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998705/mysql-problem-error-1064-42000)

Comment: The tags you chose are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Add a trailing comma to the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read from a file:

```
shell> mysql db_name < text_file
```

where text_file has the content:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  hashed_password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KAEY (id)
);
```

[More info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, just delete the line "username VARCHAR", you are not giving size neither the continuation ",", and it already exist in the next line, so your code should be as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  hashed_password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```